# How to cache/save external API's

Tags: php, xml, json, api

i was looking at how to save/cache external api because when the external api's are not working then it makes my website full of errors. i would like to know a way to cache api.
i would take an example of http://steamcommunity.com/id/712?xml=1 
it often goes down and i would also take an example of json formatted api's but couldn't find any api without an api key still this is an json api - http://api.steampowered.com/IEconItems_440/GetSchema/v0001/?key=&language=en
Some help would really be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: You cant save external api since its on external site, however you can cache the return data for specif URL calls, and once the api is down you can load data from cache. There are several options to store data viz - memcache, radis etc, where your key will the specific API URL and data is returned data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can roll your own wrapper for that. The workflow as follows:

- Check if a that you get exists in a cache
- If it does, then you'd retrieve it
- if does not, then you grab all content from desired url and store it in a cache

-This would look like this,

```
$cache = new YourOwnCacheManager(array(
   'ttl' => 60,
   'path' => '/temp.cache'
));


$url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/id/712?xml=1'


if ($cache->isCached($url)) {

   $content = $cache->read($url);

} else {

   $content = file_get_contents($url);
   $cache->write($url, $content);
}

echo $content;
```