# How to parse steam user inventory without bans

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, steam, inventory

If I will use standart link to parse Steam user inventory 
  (https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{ steamid } /inventory/json/730/2) 
 more than 2-3 times per minute, I will get banned from Steam api to 5 mins. How can I parse it without bans? Using node.js.

Comment: make the calls from several different servers. for example, a simple php script can "launder" the origin of the request and spit out the response to a master app.

Comment: I'm sayed, that I'm using node.js, not php.

Answer (score 2):

Store the result you get from your first request, and re-use it instead of re-querying Steam every time you want to read the data.
pseudocode:

```
if(!cache) 
    getDataFromSteam()
    saveDataToCache()
else
    getDataFromCache()
```

Comment: Why not? [Other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21135570) suggest using a cache as well, and large sites such as tf2wh also rely on a caching system, as it's not likely that a user's inventory will change multiple times in a short period.

Comment: Okay, right now I'm using API of my friend (he don't want to tell me how he doing it). My site in average have 100-200 online and there are a lot of new users. I need to load inventory without any bans, because it is not serious

Answer (score 0):

If you send too many requests you are sending too many requests. That is a fact you have to accept and work with that. I know from testing on my own that you are limited to 200 calls in 5 minutes. You have several options:

- Implement a routine that limits the calls to 200 in 5 minutes and not more in order to avoid getting banned.
- Cache the calls you make in order to avoid duplicate calls for one user.
- Use other IP adresses as mentioned by @Dandavis.